# couchbase: what is the auto_failover_node alert?

Tags: couchbase

my trusty couchbase cluster (version 4.6) is emitting an "auto_failover_node" alert. I think I understand what auto-failover means, but I dont understand the meaning of the alert.

does it mean that the cluster has performed auto-failover? documentation on this topic is very scarce.

Answer (score 1):

ok. I *did* find an answer in the alert email that couchbase sent:
"Node ('ns_1@ip-10-32-3-207.ec2.internal') was automatically failovered."

so I guess the alert is raised whenever a node is auto-failovered.

Comment: I think you are correct. Since you think there is a documentation issue, can I ask your feedback? Where do you think this detail should appear in the documentation that it doesn't?

Comment: thanks for your comment. TBH, I dont usually care where thing are - as long as they can be googled. I can think of a few options: perhaps (simply) in a list of alerts emitted by CB. in addition, I stumbled on a page with the list of errors in the UI (http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html#/settings/alerts) so maybe there should be some documentation about the UI, which would also detail the alerts.

Comment: There's definitely documentation about the alerts here: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/settings/configure-alerts.html

Comment: But you are looking for maybe the various codes to be part of that?

Comment: exactly so. I'd never find the page otherwise.

Comment: I've created a ticket to address this in the documentation, you may want to keep an eye on it: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-3346